# Best way to calculate data of entrys in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

im quite new to MVC and am finding it hard to find resources on stuff like this

I have a model:

```
public class Distance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Distance Run")]
    public float DistanceRun { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Chose a date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime _Date { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Any Addtional Comments")]
    public String AdditionalComments { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to display on my view of this model all total Distance run, in the top corner. Would it be best to use the whole:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DistanceRun)Km
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item._Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdditionalComments)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Foreach loop to calculate it by adding each Distance KM or would it make sense to create a near to identical view with its own separate action in a controller to calculate distance?

Comment: So the view's model is actually a collection of that model object?  Wouldn't the "total distance" then simply be `Model.Sum(d => d.DistanceRun)` ?

Comment: @David oh, sorry I didn't even know you could do that. If you write that as an answer i will happy accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code in the view, it looks like the view model is actually a *collection* of that particular model.  Something like:

```
@model IEnumerable<Distance>
```

(or anything similar, it makes little difference for this)

If that's the case then your view already has the data it needs, you just need to bind to it.  A calculated value doesn't need any kind of two-way binding, so you can just output it to the page wherever you like.  Something as simple as this:

```
Total Distance: @Model.Sum(d => d.DistanceRun)
```

You can include any formatting you like, perhaps by appending a `.ToString()` with a custom format.  But binding to the model in this case is as simple as just outputting the value like that.

Comment: i didn't know that view can communicate with model before

Comment: @Rise: The view can read any information that's on the model provided to it.  That's part of the nature of the MVC pattern in general.

Answer (score 1):

As noted from the comments, you've actually got a collection of `Distance` as the model for the view. I propose you create a new ViewModel for this view such as:

```
public class DistancesViewModel 
{
    public ICollection<Distance> Distances { get; set; }

    public int TotalDistanceRun {  
        get {
            return Distances.Sum(d => d.DistanceRun)
        }
    }
}
```

Then bind your View to that ViewModel instead. You can then access `@Model.TotalDistanceRun` and still use the Distances in a loop etc via `Model.Distances`.

The advantage for me in this approach is avoiding code on the view as you may need to change how the total distance is calculated at some point and doing it on the ViewModel is cleaner.